# Investigating Primes Below a Bound That Do Not Divide Sequences Generated by Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

I am interested in questions about the interaction between prime numbers and sequences generated by specific functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. I'm particularly interested in sequences like $k2^n+1$ (akin to Sierpiński numbers) but wish to extend this question to other sequences or functions. The core question is: For given a sequence generated by a function, can we find primes, specifically below a known bound $B$, that do not divide any number in this sequence?

This question might be clearer if we consider an example. Take numbers of the form $k2^n+1$. For every $k$ can we find a prime $p\leq B$ for some bound $B$ such that $p\nmid k2^n+1$.

Do any analogous inquiries or proofs exist for sequences produced by other functions. It touches upon the broader mathematical challenge of identifying primes in relation to sequences, within a specified bound.

Key Points of Interest:

1. Existence of Primes Below Bound $B$: How can we establish the
   existence of primes $p \leq B$ that do not divide any number in a
   given sequence? This includes not just $k2^n+1$, but also other
   sequences that might exhibit properties in relation to prime
   numbers.
2. Scope of Sequences and Functions: What other sequences or functions
   have been studied in this context? This could encompass sequences
   defined by polynomial, exponential, or more complex functions, where
   the sequence might interact with prime numbers in significant ways.
3. Methodological Approaches: What approaches, whether from analytic
   number theory, computational methods, or other areas, have been
   applied to explore these questions? Are there specific tools or
   techniques that have proven particularly effective?
4. Case Studies and Examples: Are there notable examples where a proof
   or a comprehensive search has identified primes that meet these
   criteria for specific sequences or functions? Insights from these
   examples could provide valuable lessons and strategies for tackling
   similar problems.

Can anyone shed light on these questions? Whether it's sharing known results, conjectures, methodologies, case studies, or letting me know why this is a silly question, your input is appreciated. I'm particularly keen on learning about any work that has explored the existence of non-dividing primes below a known bound in the context of various sequences.